# Adding JAVA_HOME to system variable Path via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I'm trying to add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `Path` environment variables via Powershell script.

The `JAVA_HOME` variable itself is pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172`.

When I added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` manually from the Environment Variable window

[image: Environment Variable]

Then call this line of code from Powershell to get value of `Path` variable

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

It seems like the result from executing line above converts `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the actual path that I've defined which is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172`.

The output look like this

```
...;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;
```

But when I added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` via Powershell script with the code below

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + "%JAVA_HOME%\bin", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Then run `GetEnvironmentVariable` function again, the output is different than when I added the path through the environment variable window. It doesn't convert `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the actual path.

The output looks like this

```
....;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Is this expected? Or is there something that I am missing?

I can actually just append the real path to `Path` variable directly, but I want to make use of `JAVA_HOME` variable so the path will be in 1 location.

Answer (score 20):

After I installed JAVA from oracle website I set

```
 [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1")
```

To set java in the path I did,

```
 [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + ";$($env:JAVA_HOME)\bin")
```

Worked like a charm!

If you want to have it load up automatically when you open powershell you can do,

```
New-Item $profile -Type File -Force
```

and open in notepad like

```
notepad.exe $profile
```

and paste in

```
 [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1")
 [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + ";$($env:JAVA_HOME)\bin")
```

You can close the notepad now!
Next, you want to allow powershell to run the ps script so don't forget to grant unrestricted access to running the profile script on load by,

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

Java should now be loaded after you reopen powershell. Thats it!

Comment: I must add the in order for me to work I needed to change the order in PATH due to priority. Instead adding: `$($env:JAVA_HOME)\bin` at the end, I did it at the start. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

First you can use the following syntax to reach then environememnt variable in PowerShell :

```
$env:Path
```

So in your case you can write :

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + "$($Env:JAVA_HOME)\bin", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Here is an example :

```
PS C:\> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "c:\temp")
PS C:\> $env:JAVA_HOME
c:\temp

PS C:\> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TEST", "$($Env:JAVA_HOME);c\docs")

PS C:\> $env:TEST
c:\temp;c\docs
```

---

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
# example of adding a path to PATH
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $Env:Path + ";$($Env:JAVA_HOME)\bin", "User")
```

---

**Be carefull** : `$Env:Path` is the merge of *System Path* and *User Path*. Depending on the user who executes this command, the resulting *Path* will contain different entries (both user profile ones and original system ones). If you really want to change only system ones you should use :

```
$oldSysPath = (Get-Itemproperty -path 'hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\control\session manager\environment' -Name Path).Path
$newSysPath = $oldSysPath + ";$($Env:JAVA_HOME)\bin"

Set-ItemProperty -path 'hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\control\session manager\environment' -Name Path -Value $newSysPath
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will just add the path directly to the `TEST` environment variable. I actually want to add a dynamic path from powershell by adding `%JAVA_HOME%` (like how we can do it from the environment variable window) so if one day the path for JAVA_HOME change, it will be reflected in others that uses `%JAVA_HOME%` (Like `Path`). Is this possible?

Comment: So weird that the environment can be accessed by `$env:Path`, when like all of Powershell uses commandlets in the form <VERB>-<OBJECT>

Answer (score 4):

```
# START POWERSHELL7
start-process "c:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -verb runas
# ADD "JAVA_HOME"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "c:\opt\jdk-15", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
# ADD "bin += path"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;" + [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine), [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```